# Is it possible to get rid of "Index" with ASP.NET FriendlyUrls?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms, friendly-url

Currently I'm using the (rather) new [ASP.NET FriendlyUrls](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingASPNETFriendlyUrlsCleanerURLsEasierRoutingAndMobileViewsForASPNETWebForms.aspx) feature in my WebForms .NET 4.5 application to make the URLs look cleaner.

What I'm trying to achieve is to even get rid of the "index" since it is the default of a folder.

I.e.:

```
http://www.some-server.com/my/folder/with/index.aspx <== Before FriendlyUrls
http://www.some-server.com/my/folder/with/index      <== What I have
http://www.some-server.com/my/folder/with            <== What I want
```

I've tried to derive my own URL resolver class from the built-in class `WebFormsFriendlyUrlResolver`, overwrite the function

```
public override string ConvertToFriendlyUrl(string path)
```

and then pass it to the `EnableFriendlyURls` extension method during registering routes and then strip the "index" in this override.

Unfortunately it seems that ASPX file URLs are not being passed at all to my derived class.

**So my question is:**

How to make the ASP.NET FriendlyUrls feature remove an "index.aspx" part completely instead of just the ".aspx"?

Comment: What happens when you browse to just the folder? Does adding `index.aspx` as a `Default Document` option in `IIS` help?

Comment: Thanks, @Vaze - I could solve this probably very well with IIS rewrite stuff, I thought it would be more elegant to do it with pure ASP.NET FriendlyUrls only.

Answer (score 1):

In Webforms, if you use Default.aspx, it will use that page as the folder default automatically.

Comment: Thanks. Actually the default document feature comes with iis, not webforms. Since I want to avoid duplicate content this is not the solution I am seeking.

Comment: Are you running this on IIS?

Comment: For development I am using the vs webdev server.

Comment: There is no reason to separate your server settings from your code. In fact, many key features in ASP.NET are actually IIS settings.